# php html dom parser only saving last result to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, dom

I am using php html dom parser to gather information from 2 sites and when echoed it works just how i want it to but when i try and save some of my variables to a database it will only save the last result.

Here is the code i have been working on.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="betatv_local";

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


$html = file_get_html('http://www.sidereel.com/Supernatural');

// find the title and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.title') as $title)
foreach($title->find('.sr-header') as $title2)
echo $title2->plaintext .'<br>';

echo '<br>';

// find the desc and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.summary') as $desc)
foreach($desc->find('.full-summary') as $descc)
echo $descc->plaintext .'<br>';


echo '<br>';

// find the showinfo and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.count') as $info)
echo $info->plaintext;



// find the airtime and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.airtime') as $air)
echo $air->plaintext;



// find the show status and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.status') as $status)
echo $status->plaintext .'<br>';

echo '<br>';

// find the show img and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.show-image') as $cover_img)
foreach($cover_img->find('img') as $cover_img_link)
echo $cover_img_link->src .'<br>';

echo '<br>';





$html = file_get_html('http://www.1channel.ch/watch-11054-Supernatural');

    // find the show episodes and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.tv_container') as $episodes)
foreach($episodes->find('a') as $episode_links)

echo $episode_links->plaintext .'<br>';


$query = "INSERT INTO tv_shows (show_name,show_info,show_airs,show_status,show_cover,show_desc,show_episodes) VALUES('$title2->plaintext','$info->plaintext','$air->plaintext','$status->plaintext','$cover_img_link->src','$descc->plaintext','$episode_links->plaintext')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

?>
```

When echoed it looks like this.

> Supernatural
>
> Jensen Ackles and Jared Padalecki star as Dean and Sam Winchester, two
>   brothers searching for the meaning behind their mother's death at the
>   hand of a demon, and their father's mysterious disappearance.
>
> 8 Seasons, 163 Episodes | Airs: 9:00 PM on The CW | Show Status:
>   Hiatus
>
> http://s3.sidereel.com/tv_shows/4373/large/sc_supernatural.jpg
>
> Season 1 Episode 1 - Pilot Episode 2 - Wendigo Episode 3 - Dead In The
>   Water Episode 4 - Phantom Traveler Episode 5 - Bloody Mary Episode 6 -
>   Skin Episode 7 - Hook Man Episode 8 - Bugs Episode 9 - Home Episode 10
>   - Asylum Episode 11 - Scarecrow Episode 12 - Faith Episode 13 - Route 666 Episode 14 - Nightmare Episode 15 - The Benders Episode 16 -
>   Shadow Episode 17 - Hell House Episode 18 - Something Wicked Episode
>   19 - Provenance Episode 20 - Dead Man's Blood Episode 21 - Salvation
>   Episode 22 - Devil's Trap Season 2 Episode 1 - In My Time of Dying
>   Episode 2 - Everybody Loves A Clown Episode 3 - Bloodlust Episode 4 -
>   Children Shouldn't Play With Dead Things Episode 5 - Simon Said
>   Episode 6 - No Exit Episode 7 - The Usual Suspects Episode 8 -
>   Crossroad Blues Episode 9 - Croatoan Episode 10 - Hunted Episode 11 -
>   Playthings Episode 12 - Nightshifter Episode 13 - Houses of the Holy
>   Episode 14 - Born Under A Bad Sign Episode 15 - Tall Tales Episode 16
>   - Roadkill Episode 17 - Heart Episode 18 - Hollywood Babylon Episode 19 - Folsom Prison Blues Episode 20 - What Is and What Should Never Be
>   Episode 21 - All Hell Breaks Loose, Part 1 Episode 22 - All Hell
>   Breaks Loose, Part 2 Season 3 Episode 0 - Promo Episode 1 - The
>   Magnificent Seven Episode 2 - The Kids Are Alright Episode 3 - Bad Day
>   at Black Rock Episode 4 - Sin City Episode 5 - Bedtime Stories Episode
>   6 - Red Sky At Morning Episode 7 - Fresh Blood Episode 8 - A Very
>   Supernatural Christmas Episode 9 - Malleus Maleficarum Episode 10 -
>   Dream A Little Dream Of Me Episode 11 - Mystery Spot Episode 12 - Jus
>   In Bello Episode 13 - Ghostfacers Episode 14 - Long-Distance Call
>   Episode 15 - Time Is On My Side Episode 16 - No Rest For The Wicked
>   Season 4 Episode 0 - Promo Episode 1 - Lazarus Rising Episode 2 - Are
>   You There God? It's Me, Dean Winchester Episode 3 - In the Beginning
>   Episode 4 - Metamorphosis Episode 5 - Monster Movie Episode 6 - Yellow
>   Fever Episode 7 - It's the Great Pumpkin, Sam Winchester Episode 8 -
>   Wishful Thinking Episode 9 - I Know What You Did Last Summer Episode
>   10 - Heaven and Hell Episode 11 - Family Remains Episode 12 - Criss
>   Angel Is a Douchebag Episode 13 - After School Special Episode 14 -
>   Sex and Violence Episode 15 - Death Takes a Holiday Episode 16 - On
>   the Head of a Pin Episode 17 - It's a Terrible Life Episode 18 - The
>   Monster at the End of This Book Episode 19 - Jump the Shark Episode 20
>   - The Rapture Episode 21 - When the Levee Breaks Episode 22 - Lucifer Rising Season 5 Episode 0 - Promo Episode 1 - Sympathy for the Devil
>   Episode 2 - Good God, Y'all! Episode 3 - Free to Be You and Me Episode
>   4 - The End Episode 5 - Fallen Idol Episode 6 - I Believe the Children
>   Are Our Future Episode 7 - The Curious Case of Dean Winchester Episode
>   8 - Changing Channels Episode 9 - The Real Ghostbusters Episode 10 -
>   Abandon All Hope... Episode 11 - Sam, Interrupted Episode 12 - TBA
>   Episode 13 - Back to the Future II Episode 14 - My Bloody Valentine
>   Episode 15 - Dead Men Don't Wear Plaid Episode 16 - Dark Side of the
>   Moon Episode 17 - 99 Problems Episode 18 - Point of No Return Episode
>   19 - Hammer of the Gods Episode 20 - The Devil You Know Episode 21 -
>   Two Minutes to Midnight Episode 22 - Swan Song Season 6 Episode 0 -
>   Promo Episode 1 - Exile On Main St. Episode 2 - Two and a Half Men
>   Episode 3 - The Third Man Episode 4 - Weekend at Bobby's Episode 5 -
>   Live Free or Twihard Episode 6 - You Can't Handle the Truth Episode 7
>   - Family Matters Episode 8 - All Dogs Go to Heaven Episode 9 - Clap Your Hands If You Believe Episode 10 - Caged Heat Episode 11 -
>   Appointment in Samarra Episode 12 - Like a Virgin Episode 13 -
>   Unforgiven Episode 14 - Mannequin 3: The Reckoning Episode 15 - The
>   French Mistake Episode 16 - ...And Then There Were None Episode 17 -
>   My Heart Will Go On Episode 18 - Frontierland Episode 19 - Mommy
>   Dearest Episode 20 - The Man Who Would Be King Episode 21 - Let It
>   Bleed Episode 22 - The Man Who Knew Too Much Season 7 Episode 0 -
>   Promo Episode 1 - Meet the New Boss Episode 2 - Hello Cruel World
>   Episode 3 - The Girl Next Door Episode 4 - Defending Your Life Episode
>   5 - Shut Up, Dr. Phil Episode 6 - Slash Fiction Episode 7 - The
>   Mentalists Episode 8 - Time for a Wedding! Episode 9 - How to Win
>   Friends and Influence Monsters Episode 10 - Death's Door Episode 11 -
>   Adventures in Babysitting Episode 12 - Time After Time Episode 13 -
>   The Slice Girls Episode 14 - Plucky Pennywhistle's Magic Menagerie
>   Episode 15 - Repo Man Episode 16 - Out With the Old Episode 17 - The
>   Born-Again Identity Episode 18 Episode 19 Episode 20 - The Girl With
>   the Dungeons and Dragons Tattoo Episode 21 - Reading Is Fundamental
>   Episode 22 - There Will Be Blood Episode 23 - Survival of the Fittest
>   Season 8 Episode 0 - Season 8 Promo Episode 1 - We Need to Talk About
>   Kevin Episode 2 - What's Up, Tiger Mommy? Episode 3 - Heartache
>   Episode 4 - Bitten Episode 5 - Blood Brother Episode 6 - Southern
>   Comfort Episode 7 - A Little Slice of Kevin Episode 8 - Hunteri
>   Heroici Episode 9 - Citizen Fang Episode 10 - Torn and Frayed Episode
>   11 - LARP and the Real Girl Episode 12 - As Time Goes By Episode 19 -
>   Of Grave Importance

Everything saves into the database fine except for my variable $episode_links. It only saves

> As Time Goes By Episode 19 -  Of Grave Importance

I need it to save all the information in the variable not just the last result. Any idea what im doing wrong here?

Comment: You are probably breaching the terms of use for the sites you are scraping for content, perhaps you should look at something like TVDB instead.

Comment: I am only doing this for personal use. Mainly for learning. It not like im making 1000s of requests per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php `foreach` construct executes the next statement for each item in the array.  If you want more than one thing to happen in the foreach (like echoing and saving to a database), you need to surround everything you want to happen with curly braces `{}`.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.1channel.ch/watch-11054-Supernatural');
$ep_links = "";

// find the show episodes and echo it out
foreach($html->find('.tv_container') as $episodes) {
    foreach($episodes->find('a') as $episode_links) {

        echo $episode_links->plaintext .'<br>';
        $ep_links .= $episode_links->plaintext;
    }
}

$ep_links = mysql_real_escape_string($ep_links);
$query = "INSERT INTO tv_shows (show_name,show_info,show_airs,show_status,show_cover,show_desc,show_episodes) VALUES('$title2->plaintext','$info->plaintext','$air->plaintext','$status->plaintext','$cover_img_link->src','$descc->plaintext','$ep_links')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// clean up memory
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

Edited to append each episode to a variable as it's parsing, and then insert that into the database.

Comment: That inserts and new row for each episode. I only want it to grab all the information and it be saved in the column show_episodes with one row entry.

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer to do that.  You may want to edit the line $ep_links .= $episode_links->plaintext to make the resulting string a little prettier.

Comment: I tried that but nothing saves to DB with that code and i get a error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Blood Episode 21 ' at line 1`

Comment: The episode has an apostrophe.  Input to the database should be escaped with something like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before you run query